# How to open a new page in the same windows in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I am developing a project in javafx using NetBeans IDE. I want to open a new page in the same window. How to do it ? I will provide the code below. I don't included the import statements here. Its in my actual code.

```
package welcomepage;

public class WelcomePage extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // Use a border pane as the root for scene
        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();

        border.setTop(addVBox());
        border.setLeft(addVBox1());

        Scene scene = new Scene(border,700,450);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        scene.getStylesheets().add
        (WelcomePage.class.getResource("WelcomePage.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.show();

    }

    private VBox addVBox() {

        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 12, 5, 20));
        vbox.setSpacing(10);   // Gap between nodes
        //vbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #999999;");

        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("logo11.png"));
        Label lb1=new Label("    C - MARK AND ATTENDANCE CALCULATOR");
        lb1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        lb1.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,28));
        lb1.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        lb1.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(lb1);

        return vbox;
    }

    private VBox addVBox1()
    {
        VBox vbox1=new VBox();
        vbox1.setPadding(new Insets(20, 2, 15, 20));
        vbox1.setSpacing(20);


        Button btnl2=new Button("SIGN IN");
        btnl2.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
        btnl2.setPrefSize(300,60);
        btnl2.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066cc;");
        //Image imageOk = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("icon22.png"));
        //btnl2.setGraphic(new ImageView(imageOk));

        final Tooltip tooltip2 = new Tooltip();
        tooltip2.setText("If you have an account,\nSign in here.");
        btnl2.setTooltip(tooltip2);

        btnl2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                signin();
            }
        });


        Button btnl4=new Button("HELP");
        btnl4.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
        btnl4.setPrefSize(300,60);
        btnl4.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066cc;");

        final Tooltip tooltip4 = new Tooltip();
        tooltip4.setText("Get help content\nabout this software.");
        btnl4.setTooltip(tooltip4);

        btnl4.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                help();
            }
        });

        Button btnl5=new Button("ABOUT");
        btnl5.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
        btnl5.setPrefSize(300,60);
        btnl5.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066cc;");

        final Tooltip tooltip5 = new Tooltip();
        tooltip5.setText("Know about\nthis software.");
        btnl5.setTooltip(tooltip5);

        btnl5.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
             @Override
             public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                 about();
             }
        });

        Button btnl6=new Button("EXIT");
        btnl6.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
        btnl6.setPrefSize(300,60);
        btnl6.setStyle(" -fx-base: #0066cc;");
        //Image imageOk = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("cross.png"));
        //btnr3.setGraphic(new ImageView(imageOk));

        final Tooltip tooltip6 = new Tooltip();
        tooltip6.setText("Exit if you had\nfinished your works.");
        btnl6.setTooltip(tooltip6);

        btnl6.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        vbox1.getChildren().addAll(btnl2,btnl4,btnl5,btnl6);

        return vbox1;
    }

    public void signin()
    {
        Stage stage=new Stage();
        BorderPane border = new BorderPane();

        border.setTop(loginHBox1());
        border.setLeft(loginVBox1());
        border.setRight(loginVBox2());

        Scene scene = new Scene(border,700,450);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        scene.getStylesheets().add
        (Login.class.getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.show();

    }

    private HBox loginHBox1() {

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 10, 180));
        hbox.setSpacing(10);   // Gap between nodes

        Label lb1=new Label("LOG IN OR CREATE NEW ACCOUNT");
        lb1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        lb1.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,26));
        lb1.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(lb1);

        return hbox;
    }

    private VBox loginVBox1() {

        VBox hbox = new VBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20,30,15,50)); // Set all sides to 10
        hbox.setSpacing(10);     // Gap between nodes

        Label lb3=new Label("LOG  IN");
        lb3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        lb3.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,24));
        lb3.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

        Label lb1=new Label("Username");
        lb1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        lb1.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
        lb1.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

        TextField t1=new TextField();
        t1.setPrefSize(150,30);

        Label lb2=new Label("Password");
        lb2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        lb2.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
        lb2.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

        PasswordField pw1=new PasswordField();
        pw1.setPrefSize(150,30);

        Button b1=new Button("LOG IN");
        b1.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,16));
        b1.setPrefSize(80,5);

        hbox.getChildren().addAll(lb3,lb1,t1,lb2,pw1,b1);

        return hbox;
    }

    private VBox loginVBox2()
    {
       VBox hbox1 = new VBox();
       hbox1.setPadding(new Insets(15, 50, 15, 10));
       hbox1.setSpacing(10);

       Label lb4=new Label("CREATE  NEW  ACCOUNT");
       lb4.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,24));
       lb4.setPrefSize(250,30);
       lb4.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

       Label lb1=new Label("Full Name ");
       lb1.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,18));
       lb1.setPrefSize(100, 30);
       lb1.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

       TextField t1=new TextField();
       t1.setPrefSize(50,30);

       Label lb2=new Label("User Name ");
       lb2.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,18));
       lb2.setPrefSize(150, 30);
       lb2.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

       TextField t2=new TextField();
       t2.setPrefSize(100,30);

       Label lb3=new Label("Password ");
       lb3.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,18));
       lb3.setPrefSize(150, 30);
       lb3.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

       PasswordField t3=new PasswordField();
       t3.setPrefSize(100,30);

       Label lb5=new Label("Gender ");
       lb5.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,18));
       lb5.setPrefSize(150, 30);
       lb5.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

       ObservableList<String> options2 = 
       FXCollections.observableArrayList(
       "Male","Female");
       final ComboBox comboBox2 = new ComboBox(options2);
       comboBox2.setPrefSize(250,30);

       Button btn1=new Button("CREATE");
       btn1.setFont(Font.font("Calibri",FontWeight.BOLD,18));
       btn1.setPrefSize(100,30);


       hbox1.getChildren().addAll(lb4,lb1,t1,lb2,t2,lb3,t3,lb5,comboBox2,btn1);
       return hbox1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: try this here you can open a another file in pane 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252007/loading-fxml-files-inside-a-main-fxml-file

Comment: @AnshulParashar Well am not having any fxml file. What to do now ?

Comment: use `scene.setRoot()`

Comment: @SergeyGrinev Can you give a detailed description ?

Comment: if you need a new "page" which actually is just a scenegraph component like VBox or BorderPane just set a new value to `scene.setRoot()` or any subcomponents. See example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309802/how-can-i-implement-the-functionality-of-awt-cardlayout-in-my-javafx-2-0-applica/8310585#8310585

Answer (score 2):

You can keep any Pane in the Root node 
And then through on Action of the Next Button You Can load the another node into the Parent Node.